# Delphi, VirtualStringTree - classes (objects) instead of records

Tags: delphi, class, delphi-7, virtualtreeview

I need to use a class instead of record for VirtualStringTree node.

Should I declare it standard (but in this case - tricky) way like that:

```
PNode = ^TNode;
TNode = record
 obj: TMyObject;
end;
//..
var
 fNd: PNode;
begin
fNd:= vstTree.getNodeData(vstTree.AddChild(nil));
fNd.obj:= TMyObject.Create; 
//..
```

or should I use directly `TMyObject`? If so - how?!
How about assigning (constructing) the object and freeing it?

Thanks in advance
m.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Setup datasize for holding object

   ```
   vstTree.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TMyObject);
   ```
2. Get the datasize holder and bind to your object

   ```
   vstTree.getNodeData(passed in interested node)^ := your object
   ```

   or

   ```
   vstTree.getNodeData(vstTree.AddChild(nil))^ := TMyObject.Create;
   ```

   or
   use vstTree.InsertNode method
3. To free the binding object hookup the OnFreeNode event

   ```
   vstTree.OnFreeNode := FreeNodeMethod;
   ```

   with

   ```
   procedure TFoo.FreeNodeMethod(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
   var
     P: ^TMyObject;
   begin
     P := Sender.getNodeData(Node);
     if P <> nil then
     begin
         P^.Free;
         P^ := nil; //for your safety or you can omit this line
     end;
   end;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

you could create the object instance after receiving the node data, as in :

```
fNd:= vstTree.getNodeData(vstTree.AddChild(nil)); 
fnd.obj := TMbyObject.Create;
```

or you could try and assign it directly

`Pointer(Obj) := vstTree.getNodeData(...);`

Answer (score 1):

And you can free your object in OnFreeNode event.

Comment: This should be a comment to Aldo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an object reference to your record. Use the `OnInitNode` and `OnFreeNode` events to create and destroy your object.