# Is there any trade-offs by using classes objects instead of records in VirtualStringTree?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, virtualtreeview

Regarding: [Delphi, VirtualStringTree - classes (objects) instead of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288461/delphi-virtualstringtree-classes-objects-instead-of-records)

Does the memory increases or something?

PS: I am using Delphi 2007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two drawbacks to using objects instead of records.  First, each object is 4 bytes larger than a record containing the same data would be.  (Or 8 bytes, from D2009 on.)

Second, an object has to be created and destroyed; it's not "just there" the way a record is.  But from the other question, it looks like your records have to be referred to through pointers anyway, so that's not much of a difference.  You'd still have to dynamically allocate your records and free them later.

But if you use an object you gain a lot of extra flexibility, especially the ability to use inheritance and polymorphism.  It's definitely worth the extra 4 bytes.

Comment: Since much focus of VirtualStringTree goes into speed I suspect the "not having to create and destroy" part is the biggest reason.